# SignalR - Server side method to detect if a client disconnects from a hub?

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-mvc-5, system.timers.timer

I'm wanting to stop a `System.Timers.Timer` that is running in a SignalR hub after a client closes a window/tab containing the active connection.

I have tried sending a bool value to the server by calling server code to notify the server the client is still connected or not, but it's not currently working.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    profile.server.setIsConnected(false);
};
```

Server Side:

```
public ProfileHub()
{  
    timer = new Timer(15000);
    timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => { timer_Elapsed(sender, e, _isActive); };
    timer.AutoReset = false;
}

[Authorize]
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e, bool active)
{            
    timer.Stop();

    if (active)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Timer Started");
        timer.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Timer Stopped");
        return;
    }
    // process code
}

[Authorize]
public void SetIsActive(bool isActive)
{
    _isActive = isActive;
}
```

Is this possible and am I on the right track? I suspect it has something to do with the anonymous delegate for `timer.Elapsed`, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Got solution for this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

SignalR has OnConnected, OnDisconnected, and OnReconnected that are called every time the client does one of those actions.  You can simply override them:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    return base.OnConnected();
}

public override Task OnDisconnected()
{
    //custom logic here
    return base.OnDisconnected();
}

public override Task OnReconnected()
{
    return base.OnReconnected();
}
```

I've found them to be extremely useful also for debugging purposes.  If you're wanting to set a timer for each person, you should use some sort of connectionMapping along with the above functions to keep track of your users.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! This is just what I needed. I will look at connection mapping to keep track of each timer.

Comment: Sure thing. I use a slightly modified version of the `In-Memory Storage` code presented [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections) and it works great

Answer (score 3):

You should use the method `OnDisconnected` instead of the timer. [Here's](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#onreconnected) the official documentation, but the framework gives you events when a connected client disconnects or reconnects.

Comment: OnDisconnected does not always fire though

Comment: But on all his scenarios: "The OnDisconnected method doesn't get called in some scenarios, such as when a server goes down or the App Domain gets recycled." So id DOES always fire if the Client is the reason for disconnecting.